# get_posts includes "auto drafts"?

Tags: posts, get-posts, post-status

I'm using get_posts to generate a list of posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'numberposts'       => -1,
    'post_status'       => array('publish'),
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters'  => false
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

However, the list includes posts named *"Auto-Draft"*, even though I do not include them in the `'post_status'` parameter. As far as I read those Auto-Drafts should be only existing for 7 days, but the posts that show up in the list are far older than 7 days.

Anything I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: I do not get auto-drafts when I run that code. I suspect that your theme or a plugin is applying a filter. Disable your plugins and switch themes. See if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: Hey s_ha_dum, thanks. I already tried that and even with all plugins disabled and Twenty Twelve theme it does list "Auto draft" posts.

Comment: Seems that you got `revisions` in your post types array. Check that.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to return published posts, you can exclude the 'post_status' argument as by default it will just return published posts only.

Having said that, the array works for me too though.

Comment: If the user is already explicitly asking for only `publish`ed posts, why would relying on the default value (which is actually `inherit`) result in only published posts being returned?

Comment: If you check the documentation for get_posts at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts, you'll see that the default usage of get_posts specifies: 
`'post_status'      => 'publish'`
So your down votes are both incorrect and unwarranted.

Comment: The codex is wrong, but I was partially wrong too. The default is based on whether the post is an attachment (inherit) or not (publish). That said, `inherit` being the default was not my primary point. My point was that relying on the default setting when when the current explicit setting is equivalent will not solve anything.

Comment: Ok well whether it is 'inherit' or 'publish' what I have stated does work and does solve the OP's question so it is therefore a correct answer to the question at hand, so it both should not be down-voted and to be honest also trumps any 'point' someone might want to make and solves a lot more than an unconstructive downvote. Not only that it is less code and is arguably therefore a better solution to the problem. Additionally I stated that the array does work, which should lead the OP to the conclusion that the problem lies elsewhere, whether he takes the array approach or omits the parameter.

Comment: the point is to answer the question. Omitting an optional parameter doesn't resolve the question of why `Auto-Draft` values older than 7 days are being returned. I'm not trying to be pedantic. I downvoted not because of what the default value is, but because the question is not answered.

Comment: Yes, the point is to answer @Alphawolf's question of "What am I missing?" regarding using the `get_posts` function, and the answer he is not missing anything regarding that function, as his code does what it's supposed to do and does not include 'auto-drafts', and therefore that the problem must be elsewhere in code not provided, as what he/she provided *works* to not include auto-drafts. My answer provides 2 separate ways for @Alphawolf to determine this for him/her self. So it exactly answers the question.

Comment: Additionally, irrespective of opinion as to whether it is a correct answer or not, only incorrect answers should be voted down, and it is not incorrect.